# how install IOS 12.4.4 simulator on xcode11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

I developed an IOS app and I want to check if everything is working IOS 12 and I don't have physical device running IOS 12 so how can I install IOS 12 simulator

**I tried to download simulator in components but I'm getting unable to download error**

[image]

so I need to understand

- is it possible to install earlier IOS version in xcode11 (if yes how)
- is there third-party application IOS simulators (like android genymotion)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to install earlier iOS version Simulator in Xcode 11

For Download Simulator Follow Step are as under:

Step 1: Click the Simulators

[image]

Step 2: Click Download Simulators

[image]

Step 3: Download iOS 12.4 Simulator

[image]

See I download iOS 12.4 Simulator in Xcode 11.2.1

[image]

Comment: yeah thanks for your help I did this and you can see my screen shot did you handle such a that error please